# How do I negate a 要……了 structure?

Tags: grammar

If someone says:

> 要下雨了。

But I want to deny that statement, how would I do that? I thought about 不会下雨, but it seems as if I'm using another grammar. Is there a way closer to 要……了 that I can use to negate the sentence? Would 不要下雨了 be OK?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As matter of fact, in my opinion, 不会下雨 is very good choice.

I tried to "directly" negate "要下雨了", but didn't find any way that is natural. The best I got is "不是要下雨了", which may be used to answer the question "是要下雨了吗？". It is simply a statement that "要下雨了" is not true, which may be "it won't rain", or "it is already raining heavily now", or something else.

Another way of saying it is "下不了雨", which means "it won't rain/it is not possible to rain".

Comment: 下不了雨is much better.as a Chinese,this is what we are most likely to say.不会下雨  is fit as an answer.like 
会下雨么？
不会下雨。

Answer (score 1):

I gather that you want to contradict the speaker's prediction that it will rain soon?

So, if you insist on having some common words, then 将不要下雨, "It will not rain"

But a better rebuttal would be 不应该下雨, "It should not rain", since both of you are not absolutely sure it will rain or not.

Comment: 将不要下雨 does not sound natural

Answer (score 1):

As always, it depends on what you want to negate. There is no 'one size fits all'.

1. 我们（将）要放暑假了。negate: 还早着呢。
2. 我要睡觉了。reply: 不行，你要陪我出去玩儿。
3. 我觉得天要下雨了。negate: 不是（的）
4. 约翰要娶凯特了。negate: 不是（的）

Answer (score 0):

不會下雨 is ok.

不要下雨了 is not ok. It means "stop raining".

> it seems as if I'm using another grammar.

It is ok regardless of whether or not you are using the same grammar.